# Using a for-loop to download images and save to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I currently have a for loop used to download images from urls stored in arrays. I keep having the issue of seeing the same image after every 2 or 3 new image fetches. Every time I fetch new images, I can see it's using different urls to download images but the images in the arrays are the same.

here is my code below:

```
 func downloadImageDetailsFromFlickr(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        self.imageLoading(is: true)
        flickrClient.getImageDetailsFromFlickr(lat: latitude, lon: longitude) { (photo, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.photoStore = []
                for image in photo {
                    if image.url_m.count == 0 {
                        self.imageLabel.isHidden = false
                        self.imageLoading(is: false)
                        completion(false, nil)
                    } else {
                      self.photoStore.append(image.url_m)
                        print(self.photoStore)
                        completion(true, nil)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error in the fetch image block")
                print("problem in downloading details.")
                completion(false, error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func downloadImage(completion: @escaping(Bool, Error?) -> Void ) {
        let flickrImage = FlickrImage(context: self.dataController.viewContext)
        
        for flickr in photoStore {
            self.photoUrl = ""
            self.photoUrl = flickr
        }
            flickrClient.getImage(imageUrl: photoUrl ?? "") { (data, error) in
                if error == nil {
                self.imageLoading(is: false)
                    flickrImage.photo = data
                    flickrImage.url = self.photoUrl
                    flickrImage.locations = self.location
                    flickrImage.locations?.latitude = self.latitude
                    flickrImage.locations?.longitude = self.longitude
                }
                else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong downloading an image")
                    }
            do {
                 try self.dataController.viewContext.save()
                 self.photoStore.removeAll()
                 completion(true, nil)
                } catch {
                 print("Error saving into Core Data")
                 completion(false, error)
                }
            }
}
```

Please ignore the red box, the white box shows the images being fetched all over again. My guess  is, it has to do with core data.

[image]

Comment: This for loop `for flickr in photoStore {
            self.photoUrl = ""
            self.photoUrl = flickr
        }` is always storing the last item of the photostore in the photoUrl. What is the objective of this loop?

Comment: @luckystars I wanted it to pass in each value at a time. It worked, it eliminated repeated images in the grid layout but after fetching new images a couple times you get the same grid of images.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this will fix your problem but, may be you try use dispatchgroup()

so it will goes like this

```
 let group = DispatchGroup()
    for flickr in photoStore {
//fetch image from url here
       group.enter()
       flickrClient.getImage(imageUrl: flickr ?? "") { (data, error) in
             if error == nil {
                self.imageLoading(is: false)
                    flickrImage.photo = data
                    flickrImage.url = self.photoUrl
                    flickrImage.locations = self.location
                    flickrImage.locations?.latitude = self.latitude
                    flickrImage.locations?.longitude = self.longitude
                    group.leave()

                }
                else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong downloading an image")
                    group.leave()
                 }
        }

             group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in

              //save your dowloaded image here
                 try self?.dataController.viewContext.save()
                     self?.photoStore.removeAll()
                   
                 } catch {
                    print("Error saving into Core Data")
                }
}
```

so basically by using dispatchgroup you can group the task and run it asynchronously. It just to make sure the request is not repeted and you save the image to core data once.

Comment: thank you for responding, i tried this and the results are the same. I'm trying to figure out what other ways are there to store the passed urls and filter through them.